# How Do I merge Duplicate Cells Col A Whilst Summing Their Values In Col C Whilst Pulling Through Their identifiers In Col B Excel 2013 Using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is what I want.

[image: This is what i want]

Merge Duplicates From Column A
 
Pull Through Identifiers From Column B
Sum Values From Column C

```
Sub SkuSorter()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim wSrc As Worksheet: Set wSrc = Sheets("AR Received SKU's List 1")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With wSrc
    x = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & x)
    y = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
    rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytoRange:=.Cells(1, y), unique:=True
    Z = .Cells(.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
    y = y + 1
    .Cells(1, y).Value = "Total"
    .Range(.Cells(2, y), .Cells(Z, y)).Formula = _
        "=SUMIF(" & rng.Address & "," & .Cells(2, y - 1).Address(False, False) & "," & rng.Offset(, 1).Address & ")"
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. To better assist you, we need some more input from you. Please read **[ask]**, then edit your post to contain details of what research you have done and what you have attempted to resolve this on your own. We can help you from there. As teylyn said, this is not a free coding service.

Comment: I have managed to run a vba code but have only managed to merge duplicates from column a and sum values from column c, I am struggling on how to pull through the identifiers from column b as well.

Comment: Sub SkuSorter()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim wSrc As Worksheet: Set wSrc = Sheets("AR Received SKU's")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Comment: With wSrc
    x = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & x)
    y = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
    rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytoRange:=.Cells(1, y), unique:=True
    Z = .Cells(.Rows.Count, y).End(xlUp).Row
    y = y + 1
    .Cells(1, y).Value = "Total"
    .Range(.Cells(2, y), .Cells(Z, y)).Formula = _
        "=SUMIF(" & rng.Address & "," & .Cells(2, y - 1).Address(False, False) & "," & rng.Offset(, 1).Address & ")"
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = Truek
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your code. Don't put it in comments it is unreadable.

Comment: will A and B always be the same? (if A is "Hello" then B is always "World"?)

Comment: The list in column a will change different products each week but if the same product were to appear twice then yes B would be the same for both entries.

Comment: Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you will look here again.
I'll give an answer where no VBA is needed and i'll try to explain every bit.

Using the picture you shared i created an own sheet:
[image]
We start at `F2` which is the uppermost item. Simply `=A2` will do it.
Nothing much to explain here.

At `G2` comes `=IF(LEN(F2),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,A:A,0)),"")`. Knowing the second column will always be the the same to the first column it simply searches for the exact match of `F2` in range `A:A` (`MATCH`) and prints whatever is in `B:B` at the same row. (It stops at the first item found, while it doesnt matter, cus it is alwas the same). `LEN` only prevents it from from showing `#NA` if the searchstring is empty and also skips the whole array calculation.

At `H2` comes what you sugested `=IF(LEN(F2),SUMIF(A:A,F2,C:C),"")`. It simply sums all values in column `C` which have the given searchterm in column `A`. The `LEN`-part is the same like the one at `G2` while it doesn't show an error, it will pop a `0`. However, you will still get a zero if there is a serch-term and the sum is `0`.

While you can simply autofill `G2` and `H2` down as much as you need, it wont work for `F2`. But you can do that with the following formula in `F3`:

```
=IF(LEN(F2),IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(F$2:F2,A$2:A$1000)=0)*(A$2:A$1000<>""),0)+1),""),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It starts with `COUNTIF` which simply returns a binary array while each item gets a `1` if it matchs any searchstring, all other get a `0`(searching for all strings above itself `F$2:F2`). Cus we don't want to get an allready used item we turn all `0` `TRUE` (`=0`). We also don't want an `empty` item so we check for that too (`A$2:A$1000<>""`). Multiplying 2 boolean arrays is the same like having an `AND` for each pair of items while using the real `AND` would check for all items in bouth arrays to be `TRUE`. However, multiplying again gives us a binary array having `1` at each item which is not empty and is unused. `MATCH` now checks for the first `1` and returns its position-number (row). But starting at the second row gives us an offset which is nullified with `+1`. Having the position, `INDEX` gives us the string we need. `IFERROR` is only for the first `empty` solution which would return `#NA`. And the `LEN` simply skips the calculations for all cells after the first empty one.
Using the formula wizard to see what it really calculates also helps understanding. But always **doublecheck** all the `$` or the auto fill may fail.

If you still need to ask something, just write a comment. :)